# Continuous probability distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

The following is a question that is likely to be appear on my exam on Friday (tomorrow) but contextualised into a different scenario. I'm having serious difficulty figuring out how to go about answering it. If anybody has encountered something similar and could provide a step by step explanation on how to beget the answer, I would be wholly appreciative.

Dumpington is a commuter town, i.e. all those who work travel out of town to work. Its 
workforce consists of 60% men and 40% women. The distance that men travel to work 
follows a normal distribution with mean 10 miles and standard deviation 2 miles (all 
commuting distances are one-way). The distance that women travel to work follows a normal 
distribution with mean 6 miles and standard deviation 3 miles. 
(i) What is the probability that a randomly drawn worker travels between 9 and 7 miles to 
work? 
(ii) What is the proportion of the workforce that travels more than 12 miles to work?

Comment: First, let me say that this is a bit silly. How can the distance be normally distributed - that'd implay that there are *negative* commuting distances that have non-zero probability...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

1. Let $A$ be an event that a randomly drawn worker travels between $9$ and $7$ miles to work and let $B$ be an event that a randomly drawn worker is a man. Then
   $$
   \Pr(A)=\Pr(A|B)\Pr(B)+\Pr(A|B^c)\Pr(B^c).
   $$
2. Let $C$ be an event that a randomly drawn worker travels more than $12$ miles to work. Then
   $$
   \Pr(C)=\Pr(C|B)\Pr(B)+\Pr(C|B^c)\Pr(B^c).
   $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I might come across as utterly inane, but what does the little c denote? I understand all the formulae you have provided with the exception of that.

Comment: @ScottGoddard It denotes a complement of an event (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event)).

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use the law of total probability. Let $\Omega$ be your underlying probability space, i.e. the set of all workers. Then we can define *two* random variables $D$ (for distance) and $G$ (for gender). We'll assume that $G \,:\, \Omega \to \{0,1\}$ and that $G(\omega) = 0$ if worker $\omega$ is male and $G(\omega)=1$ if worker $\omega$ is female. For the distance, $D \,:\, \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, $D(\omega)$ is the (one-way) distance that worker $\omega$ travels, regardless of her or his gender.

We don't (yet) know the distribution of $D$, but we know the distributions of $D$ under the *conditions* $G = 1$ respectively $G = 0$. Formally, we know that $$\begin{eqnarray}
  P(D \leq x \mid G = 1) &=& N_{6,3}(x) \\
  P(D \leq x \mid G = 0) &=& N_{10,2}(x) \text{,}
\end{eqnarray}$$
where $N_{\mu,\sigma}(x)$ is the CDF of the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. We also know that $$\begin{eqnarray}
  P(G=1) &=& 0.4 \\
  P(G=0) &=& 0.6
\end{eqnarray}$$

The *law of total probability* then tells us that $$
  P(D \leq x) = P(D \leq x \mid G = 1)\cdot P(G=1) + P(D \leq x \mid G = 0)\cdot P(G=0)
$$
i.e. that $$
  P(D \leq x) = N_{6,3}(x)\cdot 0.4 + N_{10,2}(x)\cdot 0.6
$$